# Import CSV By Ajax in wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, csv, import

I want to import CSV via Ajax in my word-press extension. I have wondered many places and sites but not getting any result. Is this possible CSV upload via Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSVToArray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293163/1756198)
This will help you to get data from CSV file to JavaScript array and then pass that array to ajax call via POST.